# Deleting data in a list based on an integer from user input

Tags: python-3.x

The question wants me to ask a user how many items in a list that they wish to delete. (Nothing in particular just a number of items, can be random..) The input is between 1 and 4. Here is my code.

```
list2=[]
```

```
for i in range(5):
    counter = counter+1
    print("Item number : ", counter)
    ask = input("Type here to append to list: ",)
    addingList = list2.append(ask)
print("Here is your newly created list: ", list2)
i = True
t = 0

while i:
    dellist = int(input("Select the number of items to be deleted. 1 - 4"))
    if dellist not in range(1, 5):
        print("Invalid choice, Please select a number between 1-4.")
    else:
        break 

// Have also tried using the del cmd and its only removing 1 entry even tho 3/4 could be specified in input.
```

Comment: What is the problem here?

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [list slicing](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-list-slicing/)

We use the line `list = list[:-n]` to remove the n last elements of the list using negative indexing.

Working code snippet:

```
list2 = []

for i in range(5):
    print("Item number : ", i+1)
    ask = input("Type here to append to list: ",)
    addingList = list2.append(ask)
print("Here is your newly created list: ", list2)
t = 0

while True:
    dellist = int(input("Select the number of items to be deleted. 1 - 4"))
    if dellist not in range(1, 5):
        print("Invalid choice, Please select a number between 1-4.")
    else:
        list2 = list2[:-dellist]
        break
```